# An Expression for $\log\zeta(ns)$ derived from the Limit of the truncated Prime $\zeta$ Function

Tags: riemann-zeta-function, special-functions, nt.number-theory

I think, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/115230/19341), I found 
$$
P_x(s)=\sum_{p < x} \frac{1}{p^s} =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ \mu (n)}{n}
\sum_{z\in\{1,\rho\}}(-1)^{1-\delta_{1z}}
\left[
{\rm li}(t^{\frac zn-s})
\right]^{x}_2
 \tag{7}
$$

where $\rho$ are **all** the zeros (trivial and non-trivial) of $\zeta$ function.  See the linked question for more detail, corrections are welcome.
Further we know, that
$$
    P(s)=\sum_{n> 0}\frac {\mu(n)}n{\log\zeta(ns)} .
$$

So my question is

> If
>   $\lim_{x\to \infty} P_x(s)=P(s) $
>   then, by comparing coefficients, is
>   $$
> \log\zeta(ns)=\lim_{x\to \infty}
> \sum_{z\in\{1,\rho\}}(-1)^{1-\delta_{1z}}
> \left[
> {\rm li}(t^{\frac1n( z-ns)})
> \right]^{x}_2
> ?
> $$

What I got so far is:

- Could $  \displaystyle  \log \zeta(s) = s \int_0^\infty \frac{\pi(x)}{x(x^s-1)}\,dx $ be useful somehow?
- [Thanks to robjohn](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/285413/19341) it was possible to see that both coincide at least some special values:
  If $ns=1$ or $ns=\rho$, one addend in the sum diverges like $\lim_{x\to\infty} \log\left(\frac{\log(x)}{\log(2)}\right)=\infty$. So we get 
  $$
  \begin{eqnarray}
  ns=1: & \log(\zeta(1)) &=& +\infty\\
  ns=\rho: & \log(\zeta(\rho)) &=& -\infty 
  \end{eqnarray}
  $$
- I looked at the series expansion at $s=0$ for ${\rm li}(x^{\frac1n(z-ns)})={\rm Ei}((\frac zn-s)\ln(x))$ and $\log\zeta(ns)$. Assuming I'm not wrong, you'll get the following when you compare the linear terms
  $$
  \log(2\pi) \overset{?}{=} 
  \lim_{x\to \infty}\sum_{z\in\{1,\rho\}}(-1)^{\delta_{1z}}
  \left[ \frac{ t^{\frac{z}n}}{z}\right]_2^x ,
  $$
  which looks a little irritating, since the RHS has to be independent of $x$ an $n$. Does this show that it's wrong at all?

Comment: Cross-posted at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/280984/19341 



Comment: I think by $z\in 1,\rho$ you mean to sum over the (one) pole and all the zeros of $\zeta(s)$.  This might be clearer if you separated out the contribution of the pole.

Comment: Yes but I wanted a compact, notation. 

Comment: See the Weierstrass factorization of $\zeta$ or the Rieamnn explicit formula $$\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \frac{-1}{s-1}+\sum_\rho \frac{1}{s-\rho} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{s+2n}-\frac{1}{2n} + C$$

Comment: @reuns ok this explains the values of $\log(\zeta(ns))$ with $ns=1,\rho$. thanks...